# how to relate array of textfields with array of list

Tags: php, html

Friends I have a form with number of list and text fields.
each table row has a list and a textfield.you can select a option from the list and add content to its related textfield. As follows,

```
<tr>
<td>
<select name="area[]">
<option>Family</option>
<option>Love</option>
<option>Marriage</option>
</select>
</td>
<td><input type="text" name="content[]"></td>
</tr>
```

As there can be any number of rows I decided to get inputs as arrays and try to use foreach() with those records.

my loop is something like this

```
<?php 
if(!empty($_POST['content'])){
    foreach($_POST['content']as $value){
    //need to get the related list value here
    }
    }
?>
```

What my problem is I can get the textfield value but how I get the related list value from my list array?

Sorry for my bad English. Hope you will advise me on this
Thanks.

Comment: If there are N rows in your table then there are N list and N textboxes , right?? Then you can have textbox index 0 equivalent to list box index 0 for row 0 then 1 then 2 and so on.  will that work?

Comment: @Ravi Yes you are correct.But i am adding,deleting rows according to my needs with Jquery. that is why i don't want to make them with index. i hope it'll be more easy to use array for this situation.but i don't know how to link those two together

Comment: @NullPointer Thanks for your advise i will update it.

Answer (score 0):

text field value isnet array try

```
<input type="text" name="content">
```

you can get value of content by

```
$_POST['content']
```

and i thik you want to get option value here

```
if( !empty($_POST['area']){
    foreach($_POST['area'] as $value){
    //need to get the related list value here
    }
}
```

Comment: But i have more than one textfields.so how i get the correct textfield value for selected list option?